# Mysql - How to find duplicate records within period of time

Tags: mysql, time, count

I have db structure like that:

```
id  ip       status  time
----------------------------------------
1   1.1.1.1  1       2016-11-11 21:37:04
2   8.8.8.8  1       2016-11-11 22:37:04
3   1.1.1.1  1       2016-11-11 21:38:04
4   8.8.8.8  0       2016-11-11 22:38:04
5   1.1.1.1  1       2016-11-11 21:39:04
6   8.8.8.8  0       2016-11-11 21:39:04
7   1.1.1.1  1       2016-11-11 21:40:04
8   8.8.8.8  1       2016-11-11 21:40:04
9   1.1.1.1  1       2016-11-11 21:41:04
10  8.8.8.8  1       2016-11-11 21:41:04
11  1.1.1.1  1       2016-11-11 21:42:04
12  8.8.8.8  0       2016-11-11 21:42:04
13  1.1.1.1  1       2016-11-11 21:43:04
14  8.8.8.8  1       2016-11-11 21:43:04
```

How to count records that have the status 0 and the difference between them is 1 min? they must be after each other.

In another meaning, if we have any number of records with same ip after each other with status 0 and the timestamp difference is 1 min or greater then add it to count.

Which would result something like that:

```
ip       time                 count
------------------------------------
8.8.8.8  2016-11-11 22:38:04  1
```

Sql Fiddle with one of the answers to test with:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b88d5d/1

thanks.

Comment: Isn't the count '2' ? ?!?

Comment: nop the count 1 because there was 1 occurrence when we found 2 state 0 after each other

Comment: if we found 3 records after each other with status 0 then the count should be 2, if found 4 then count should be 3  aka 3 minutes

Answer (score -1):

select ip,dt,count(id)as cnt from ip_check where
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,dt,NOW()) > 1 AND `status` = 0 group by ip

Comment: Pretty close but this doesn't strict 2 records with status 0, it also count if only 1 record with status 0.

Also it should create multiple records if it found multiple results with that query.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b88d5d/1

Comment: In the example I provided it should show 2 results each with count 1 for each ip since each occurred once 0 - 0  if it occurred 3 times like 0-0-0 it should be count 2